# How to run animation on EACH div as they scroll into view, vs running all animations when one div is into view

Tags: jquery, optimization, css-animations

I'm a bit of a novice here, and while I have this code working as I want it to, I'm sure there HAS to be a better way to write this.

**HOW IT WORKS**

Since the first 3 paragraphs are already in view, I run them outside the scroll function. The other 5 paragraphs only run the same animation as the first three when they are in view. Though I admit I believe they're just running as soon as div2 is hit, when I would rather them run when they are hit. (this is a side note if you have any ideas how to make that work better).

**THE GOAL**

I feel like there's a MUCH better way to write this that isn't so lengthy. If you have any insight on who to write better code in this situation I would certainly appreciate it! I would also like to know if there's way way to fire the animation (fade in and slide right) on each div as it comes into view vs the current functionality where it's running all the div (4-8) as soon as it hits div 2. (I hope that makes sense).

**HERES THE DEMO SITE**

(just in case you wanted to see where it's live)

https://stable.stable-demos.com/who-we-are/

Thank you in advance!!

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  // WHAT WE DO - ANIMATE PARAGRAPHS With FADE IN FROM LEFT
  var done = false;

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if (!done) {
      var y = $(window).scrollTop(),
        x = $('.div2').offset().top - 10;
      if (y > x) {
        done = true;
        $('.div4')
          .delay(0)
          .animate({
            opacity: 1,
            marginLeft: '+=50'
          });
      }
      if (y > x) {
        done = true;
        $('.div5')
          .delay(1000)
          .animate({
            opacity: 1,
            marginLeft: '+=50'
          });
      }
      if (y > x) {
        done = true;
        $('.div6')
          .delay(2000)
          .animate({
            opacity: 1,
            marginLeft: '+=50'
          });
      }
      if (y > x) {
        done = true;
        $('.div7')
          .delay(3000)
          .animate({
            opacity: 1,
            marginLeft: '+=50'
          });
      }
      if (y > x) {
        done = true;
        $('.div8')
          .delay(4000)
          .animate({
            opacity: 1,
            marginLeft: '+=50'
          });
      }
    }

  });


  // THESE RUN RIGHT AWAY BECAUSE THEY"RE IN VEIW
  $('.div1').delay(300).animate({
    opacity: 1,
    "margin-left": '+=50'
  }, 900);
  $('.div2').delay(1200).animate({
    opacity: 1,
    "margin-left": '+=50'
  }, 900);
  $('.div3').delay(1900).animate({
    opacity: 1,
    "margin-left": '+=50'
  }, 900);


}); // End jQuery
```

```css
.div1,
.div2,
.div3,
.div4,
.div5,
.div6,
.div7,
.div8 {
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  font-size: 12px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="min-height: 2000px">
  <div class="div1">
    <h2 class="space_groteskmedium large-font uppercase">We come in, put our heads down, work hard, and have a hell of a time doing it. we’ve built and are continuing to build a team of great people who do great work.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <h2 class="space_groteskmedium large-font uppercase">We come in, put our heads down, work hard, and have a hell of a time doing it. we’ve built and are continuing to build a team of great people who do great work.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    <h2 class="space_groteskmedium large-font uppercase">We come in, put our heads down, work hard, and have a hell of a time doing it. we’ve built and are continuing to build a team of great people who do great work.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="div4">
    <h2 class="space_groteskmedium large-font uppercase">We come in, put our heads down, work hard, and have a hell of a time doing it. we’ve built and are continuing to build a team of great people who do great work.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="div5">
    <h2 class="space_groteskmedium large-font uppercase">We come in, put our heads down, work hard, and have a hell of a time doing it. we’ve built and are continuing to build a team of great people who do great work.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="div6">
    <h2 class="space_groteskmedium large-font uppercase">We come in, put our heads down, work hard, and have a hell of a time doing it. we’ve built and are continuing to build a team of great people who do great work.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="div7">
    <h2 class="space_groteskmedium large-font uppercase">We come in, put our heads down, work hard, and have a hell of a time doing it. we’ve built and are continuing to build a team of great people who do great work.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="div8">
    <h2 class="space_groteskmedium large-font uppercase">We come in, put our heads down, work hard, and have a hell of a time doing it. we’ve built and are continuing to build a team of great people who do great work.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated the post title - The top error went away. Thanks for the input though :)

Comment: Does your code currently work?  Can you make a runnable example?  Are you asking how to make it "better"?  If all three are true, then this is off topic for StackOverflow as you are asking for a code review, not about an issue.  I would advise you to provide the question to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) for a more on topic environment.

Comment: It does work. It's essentially doing what it should do in the sense that if you went to the demo site it would appear the individual paragraphs are animating as you scroll down the page. 

The issue comes in when a user for example stops to read one of the top paragraphs, the rest will still animate because hitting div2 when scrolling starts the animation. I think arrays would be useful here, but I don't really know how to write them to work.

Comment: So there is actually something that "does not work"?  If so, that's the part that is on topic for StackOverflow, and should be clarified.

Comment: I don't mind how it's working right now. I just figured if someone had a better way to make it work on each div instead of running on the first div it hits, great. 

I'm mostly concerned at how to make what's working right now less lengthy and better written code that's more expandable in the case that we might have 100 paragraphs and this could get really lengthy.

Comment: It's not splitting hairs.  If it works as intended, this is a code review.  If something is not working, then you have an issue (within the context of StackOverflow).

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what it is you're asking me to do here. I went out of my way to be as detailed as possible. If I'm missing something, let me know what it is.

Comment: As I mentioned in my first comment, if the code works, and you can make an example of it (which you have), and you are asking if it can be done better, then you should post this question on CodeReview.  Not here.

Comment: It's a multi-question. Firstly, code review. Second, how to make this work correctly (ie: Run the animation on each div (individually) as they (individually) comes into view, vs what's happening currently where it's running the animation on EVERY div after it hits the .div2)

Comment: If it's a multi question, then that means it's too broad.  "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."

Comment: Did you want me to remove the "is there a better way to run this?" If so, just say that.

Comment: If you want to do that you can.  I'm simply informing you that you are asking an off topic question, or a too broad question, and it needs to either be moved to the correct site, or reworded to fit the site criteria.